# How to check if a GetComponent() is clicked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this in a script:

```
Button button = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCanvas").GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
```

And in that script's Update() function, I would like to do something like this:

```
if button clicked { // do something }
```

Please can someone explain how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that!

Use Inspector instead. Select your button, find Button component, navigate to OnClick() section, select GameObject that you'd like to interact with, Drag and Drop on available slot and then find suitable function.

[image: Button componen]